# Android Accordion-Style ListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm looking for a control similar to `ExpandableList` that allows me to scroll a list view, but the group header stays on the top of the screen until it is pushed off by the next group header.  The rows would collapse and expand similar to an accordion.

Initial view:

GROUP A 
  Row 1 
  Row 2 
GROUP B 
  Row 1 
  Row 2

Scrolling down would cause this sequence:

GROUP A 
  Row 2 
GROUP B 
  Row 1 
  Row 2 
GROUP C

GROUP A 
GROUP B 
  Row 1 
  Row 2 
GROUP C 
  Row 1

GROUP B 
  Row 1 
  Row 2 
GROUP C 
  Row 1 
  Row 2

Scrolling the opposite direction would have the reverse effect.

Is there something existing either in the Android SDK or something someone has previously made, or can someone point me in the right direction to creating this?

Comment: You mean a Sticky Header ListView. Search Google, you'll find the link to the project page

Comment: @FrankN.Stein please add as answer.  This is what I'm looking for.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean a Sticky Header ListView. Search Google, you'll find the link to the project page.

Here's one project: https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders
Here's another one: https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView
Another one; http://www.appance.com/headerlistview/

And this is only the first result page... ;)

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who still looking for a real word example just try this:

I have build a super light Accordion list recently via Constraint layout . It's worth to have a look at :

https://github.com/draxdave/ConstraintAccordion

[image]